# A non-zero matrix derived from a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I would like to derive a square matrix from the following linear mapping:
$$\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to M_{n,n}\,\,\,\phi(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{1}_n^T-\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{x}^T$$
where $M_{n,n}$ is the set of $n\times n$ real matrices,  $\mathbf{x}$ is $n\times 1$ vector, and $\mathbf{1}_n=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is the transpose of row vector with all entries $1$.

Here, I want to get at least one  non-zero matrix (for instance, when $n=3$) derived from $\phi$ above. Could you give me an example, please? I found the linear mapping when I read  [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042715003179) paper.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for an $n^2 \times n$ matrix representation of the linear map $\phi$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 No, it is $n\times n$. I've edited it now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, do you mean an example of one value of $x$ and $\phi(x)$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes. For instance, I want to find a nonzero matrix when $n=3$.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat  At the first glance, I thought that it would result in zero matrices.  However, JimmyK4542 understood what I wanted to ask. Thanks to JimmyK4542.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n = 3$ and $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\phi(\mathbf{x}) &= \mathbf{x}\mathbf{1}_3^T-\mathbf{1}_3\mathbf{x}^T 
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\2&2&2\\3&3&3\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}0&-1&-2\\1&0&-1\\2&1&0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

In particular, $\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}\mathbf{1}_n^T-\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{x}^T = \mathbf{0}_{n \times n}$ iff $\mathbf{x} = c\mathbf{1}_n$ for some constant $c$, i.e. all the entries of $\mathbf{x}$ are the same. So to guarantee that $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ is not zero, simply choose a vector $\mathbf{x}$ whose entries are not all identical.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand  now.